# How to Validate Radio Buttons Field in angular with reactive Forms

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have name and values ,calling from the ts side and want to validate it.the values are'nt getting from the event and it's been comming such as (on) .

```
<form [formGroup]="reactiveForm">
  <div *ngFor="let item of checkBoxValueList">
    <input 
    type="radio" 
    formControlName="yourChoice"
    [value]="item"
    (change)="event($event)"
    >
    {{item}}
  </div>
 </form>
 <pre>
 {{reactiveForm.value | json}}
</pre>
```

```
   checkBoxValueList = [
    'Reading',
    'Watching',
    'Traveling',
    'Cooking'
  ];
  reactiveForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    yourChoice: new FormControl()
  });

  constructor() {}

  edit(eve) {
    console.log(eve);
    console.log("target", eve.target.value);
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any PHP or Laravel here. Fix your tags please.

Comment: i changed it miken

Answer (score 2):

You can pass directly your value instead of event.
Try it.

```
(change)="edit(item)".
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you only need the selected value on change event and validate it. So here you can access the selected value of radio button by our reactiveForm variable.

```
event(eve) {
 console.log(eve);
 // console.log("target", eve.target.value);
 console.log(this.reactiveForm.value['yourChoice']); //this will give your selected value
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: yes i tried it and it's appearing as undefined while clicking simply on it i am finding as a (On).

Comment: @jayshah You can check out the StackBlitz Demo of your App here. It works perfectly in my case. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyfvba)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkkaf6 actually i did'nt get it.!

Comment: I tried your example and you are getting the outcome

your log is as follows:

Reading  //your outcome
Event // outcome of event log
// the other log with .on outcome

Comment: got it the issue of declaring.!

Comment: while calling as console.log(event.target.value) why it is comming such on then as it.?